# Add a document to parent folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

How do I add this doc to a parent folder? The following doesn't work.

```
drive.files.insert({
  convert: true,
  parents: [
    {
      "id":parentId
    }
  ],
  resource: {
    title: title,
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
    body: body,
  }
}, function(){
  console.log(arguments)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    drive.files.insert({
    resource: {
        title: title,
        mimeType: 'text/csv',
        parents: [ { id: parentId } ]
    },
    media: {
       mimeType: 'text/csv',
       body: body
    },
 }, function(err, resp) {});
```

Looks like the documentation may have changed: 
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/96